# How to copy layout of View which add child programatically?

Tags: java, android

My MainActivity is set orientation by horizontal, it includes 2 Framelayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.example.helloandroid.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

from MainActivity.java, frameLayout1 add some buttons programmatically , these buttons are set position random by this code belows:

```
private void addNumbers(){ // Numbers is set with random position

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("" + i);
        btn.setId(i);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        int leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(widthScreen/2 - btnSize ); 
        int topMargin = new Random().nextInt(heightScreen - btnSize);    
        lp.leftMargin = leftMargin;
        lp.topMargin = topMargin;

        btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
        framelayout1.addView(btn);
        //framelayout2.addView(btn);

    }
}
```

And I  want to make framelayout2 has a same layout with framelayout1 look like this image 
[image]

So, how can I copy layout of framelayout1 to framelayout2?
And How can recognize onclick event of buttons is on framelayout1 or framelayout2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following sample code,

```
private void addNumbers(){ // Numbers is set with random position
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        Button btn2 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(listener2); // here using different listener
        btn1.setText("" + i);
        btn2.setText("" + i); //same text

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        int leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(widthScreen/2 - btnSize ); 
        int topMargin = new Random().nextInt(heightScreen - btnSize);    
        lp.leftMargin = leftMargin;
        lp.topMargin = topMargin;

        btn1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        btn2.setLayoutParams(lp); //same lp 

        framelayout1.addView(btn1);
        framelayout2.addView(btn2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to so this as you cannot clone a View. But you can make a bitmap copy of it and display it.

```
V.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Another solution would be to iterate over all childs in frameLayout1 and reading the values you set to them and creating new views with those parameters.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < frameLayout1.getChildCount() ; ++i)
{
     View v = frameLayout1.getChildAt(i);
     // Read paddings, ... use getLayoutParams()
     //Create new views with the same parameters and add to frameLayout2
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Option1 is not a good way because we can not catch event onclick on buttons of framelayout2. I will consider option2 but I think we will get problem if the child of framelayout1 is large.

Answer (score 0):

Store id of the last created button. Then you have a new id to begin with for buttons of layout2. Run a loop as many times as buttons in layout1 and you can call `getLayoutParams()` on views sequentially and assign them to newly created buttons.

Comment: @Patel : Thank for your answer, but if do like that, code will duplicate for framelayout1 and framelayout2. And if the quantity of number is large (ex : 100, 200) , so it is not a good way.